# wp_comments table really big casuing /wp-admin/edit-comments.php to slowly load

Tags: wp-admin, comments

Our wp_comments has millions of rows.

When we load `/wp/wp-admin/edit-comments.php` it would timeout.

Looking at mysql, this simple query is taking a long time

```
SELECT  wp_comments.comment_ID FROM wp_comments  
WHERE ( ( comment_approved = '0' OR comment_approved = '1' ) ) 
AND comment_type IN ('pingback', 'trackback')
ORDER BY wp_comments.comment_date_gmt
DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Is there away to edit the `edit-comments.php` comment dashboard to work only on comments for the last year instead of every commens in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix it by putting this in functions.php

```
// fix query timeout in wp-admin/edit-comment.php page
add_action('pre_get_comments', 'pre_get_comments_any_status');
function pre_get_comments_any_status($comment_query) {
  if (empty($comment_query->query_vars['status'])) {
    $comment_query->query_vars['status'] = 'any';
  }
}
```